# How to find out what languages are available on a Symbian device using the C++ APIs?

Tags: c++, symbian, s60

Does anyone know how to query at runtime a list of display languages that a Symbian (S60, specifically) device has installed?  I've been able to query for the language set, but I haven't found anyway of getting what languages make up that set at runtime.

This needs to be the actual language code (i.e, ELangEnglish for UK English, ELangAmerican for US English, etc, etc) and not just that there is any English variant on the phone.

Thanks!

Comment: I think perhaps some clarification is required - for what purpose do you need the language set?
(The CPtiEngine class mentioned below gives you the installed languages for text input, this isn't necessarily the same as the available languages for text display)

Comment: KevinD -- good point.  I added that I am looking for the display languages, not just the text input languages.  Basically the same list as what the system will allow you to switch between and the same ones that User::Language() would return if you had switched into each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [CPtiEngine class reference](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/classCPtiEngine.html). Quoting directly from the page:

> This is main class for PtiEngine API.
>   This is the main client side API for
>   PtiEngine. The purpose of PtiEngine
>   API is to provide a single calling
>   point for all the low level (below UI)
>   text input functionality. The API
>   provides methods for querying and
>   activating installed languages,
>   changing input modes and text cases
>   and performing the actual text input
>   operations.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- specifically, the GetAvailableLanguagesL() method gave me what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok -- I have to take back my previous statement.  What PtiEngine reports back is the base language code.  For example, on a North American S60 device, it reports back English with a language code of 1, but that's incorrect -- it should be 10.  Still looking for a way to get the actual language now.